# A class of sets which is closed under the formation of finite intersections necessarily contain the universal set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How does a class of sets (may not be empty) which is closed under the formation of finite intersections necessarily contain the universal set? I came across this in G.F. Simmons (page-12).

This doubt might be very silly, but  I do not see how it follows. Can anyone please explain?

Comment: What is the intersection of an empty family of sets?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown It is the universal set. I have understood that part. But, for non-empty family  of sets, it is not clear how it follows.

Comment: The class of ordinal numbers is closed under finite intersections but this not
 contais the universe.

Comment: @Gödel I don't know much about ordinal numbers and I guess the author wrote this in connection with topological spaces only.

Comment: @Kappa each ordinal number has the order topology.

Comment: @Gödel Then that means such classes of sets may not contain the universal set. Is there any other context under which the author is writing this?

Comment: @Kappa The author says that this happens when the empty set belongs to the class, and you know $\bigcap\emptyset=U$ ($U$ denotes the universe in that book).

Comment: @Gödel That's true, he says so initially. I have understood that part. Later in the same page, he writes what I have asked about, before defining Boolean algebra of sets.

Comment: Consider the alternate definition, for all closed K, L, K $\cap$ L is in the collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To say that a family $\mathcal X$ of subsets of some universal set $U$ is closed under finite intersections means that, for any finite subfamily $\mathcal F\subseteq\mathcal U$, the intersection $\bigcap\mathcal F$ of all the sets in $\mathcal F$ is also in $\mathcal X$. In particular, since the empty family $\varnothing$ is always a finite subfamily of $\mathcal X$ (regardless of whether $\mathcal X$ itself is empty or not), and since $\bigcap\varnothing=U$, we get $U\in\mathcal X$.

Comment: "Regardless of whether $\mathcal{X}$ is empty or not", now I get it. This was where I was getting confused. Thank you so much for explaining.